# Ubuntu 22.04, “battery plugged in” icon suddenly disappeared

Tags: power-management, icons, laptop, battery

Newbie here.

I’m running up to date Ubuntu 22.04 ext4 Gnome Wayland on a MSI Bravo 15 AMD Ryzen 7 4800H laptop. Earlier today the little “battery plugged in” icon suddenly disappeared from my little battery icon. So I checked my charging cable and it’s providing a stable solid 19VDC.

So I opened my Virtual Box and then opened a Windows 10 VM. The battery icon in the Windows VM shows plugged in as normal. But the Ubuntu host battery icon shows not plugged in. It’s been about 2 hours and the battery shows no drain. It’s staying solid at 93% charge with no drain. So something caused the little “battery plugged in” icon to disappear from my Ubuntu 22.04 host.

My Ubuntu 22.04 VM also shows no “battery plugged in” icon. But the Windows VM does show the “battery plugged in” icon.

The problem persists after multiple reboots and unplugging and reconnecting the power cord. I also ran Software Updater. No effect.

Any ideas why my “battery plugged in” icon has disappeared?

Is there a terminal command that shows whether or not the power is plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

you can check battery status from UI

1.Open the Activities overview and start typing Power.

2.Click Power to open the panel. The status of Batteries and known Devices is displayed.

or you can check power status (batteries/ac-adapter/..) this command

```
upoupower -d
```

this command will show power daemon changes in realtime

```
upower -m
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... The issue fixed itself (I didn't do anything). The charging/plugged in icon is back. Don't know why or how. Shrug.